# Position HTML div based on JSON information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, json

I am creating a dashboard and I was able to save information to my database using jQuery, JSON, and a generic handler. Now, I was able to call back my database information using a WebService and JSON. My database information looks like this..

[image]

On document ready, I use this to retrieve the information from my table from JSON

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "Webservices/RetrieveWidgets.asmx/GetWidgets",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        var te = response;
        function sortResults(prop, asc) {
            te.d = te.d.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]) ? 1 : ((a[prop] < b[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
                else return (b[prop] > a[prop]) ? 1 : ((b[prop] < a[prop]) ? -1 : 0);
            });
         }

         sortResults('SortNo', true);

         for (var i = 0; i < te.d.length; i++) {
             $('#test ul').append('<li>' + te.d[i].Title + '</li>');
             console.log(te.d[i])
         }
      },
      error: function (repo) {
           console.log(repo);
           $("#console").html('<div class="fail">Dashboard could no load!</div>').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo(600, 1);
           setTimeout(function () {
              $('#console').delay(500).fadeTo(600, 0);
          }, 1000);
      }
});
```

I was helped with the above.. and for testing purposes, this was added to the HTML

```
<div id="test">
       <ul>

       </ul>
</div>
```

And this is what is displayed.

[image]

So what is happening, it's ordered by the SortNo and the title of the widgets are displayed. The first 3 are in SortNo 0, and so on. This has really helped me with passing the JSON. Here is what my dashboard looks like..

[image]

And this is what my aspx page looks like (only a single 'column' to get an idea)

```
    <div class="column" id="column1" runat="server">
        <div class="dragbox" id="CurrentDealsWidget" runat="server" visible="false">
            <h2 style="font-size: 14pt">Current Deals per Location</h2>
            <div class="dragbox-content">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvCurrentLocationTotals" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataKeyNames="InternallocationID" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC"
                    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black"
                    GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InternallocationID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LocationName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" Text="totes"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragbox" id="StorePayrollWidget" runat="server" visible="false">
            <h2 style="font-size: 14pt">Store's Payroll</h2>
            <div class="dragbox-content">

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPayrollStores" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPayrollStores_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelPayroll" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlPayrollStores" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="dragbox-content">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelOverTime" runat="server" Text="Total Overtime Hours: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalOvertime" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelHoliday" runat="server" Text="Total Holiday: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalHoliday" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelVacation" runat="server" Text="Total Vacation: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalVacation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lbllableTotalHours" runat="server" Text="Total Hours: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalStoreHours" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblLabelPay" runat="server" Text="Total Pay: " Width="350px"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblTotalPay" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <div style="align-content: center">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDetailed" runat="server" Text="Detailed Report" PostBackUrl="~/Reporting/Payroll/StorePayroll.aspx"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragbox" id="ObjectiveWidget" runat="server" visible="false">
            <h2 style="font-size: 14pt">Store Objectives-<asp:HyperLink ID="hlDaily" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Reporting/DailyReports/SalesByModel.aspx">Daily Report</asp:HyperLink></h2>
            <div class="dragbox-content">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upObjective" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlNewUsed" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div style="width: 100%">
                            <div style="text-align: center">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblObjNotice" runat="server" Text="Notice: If your dealership is in red; monthly objectives need updated!" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                                &nbsp;<br />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlObjDealership" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlObjDealership_SelectedIndexChanged" Style="height: 22px">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewUsed" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlNewUsed_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>New</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Used</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlObjectiveMake" runat="server" Width="155px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlObjectiveMake_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <table style="display: inline-block; width: 45%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommitObj" runat="server" Text="Commit OBJ: " Width="100%"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="tbCommitObj" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCommitGross" runat="server" Text="Commit Gross OBJECT: " Width="100%"></asp:Label><asp:TextBox ID="tbCommitGross" runat="server" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitDaily" runat="server" Text="Submit" Height="32px" OnClick="btnSubmitDaily_Click" Width="68px" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 100%">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDailyMess" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="float: right; width: 45%" title="Current Monthly Objectives">
                                <caption>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" Text="Current Monthly Objectives"></asp:Label></caption>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: center">
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblObj" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Obj: "></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentObj" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="text-align: center">
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblGross" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Gross: "></asp:Label>
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCurrentGross" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I use this jQuery to drag and drop the widgets..

```
$(function () {
        $('.dragbox')
        .each(function () {
            $(this).hover(function () {
                $(this).find('h2').addClass('collapse');
            }, function () {
                $(this).find('h2').removeClass('collapse');
            })
            .find('h2').hover(function () {
                $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'visible');
            }, function () {
                $(this).find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            })
            .click(function () {
                $(this).siblings('.dragbox-content').toggle();
                updateWidgetData();
            })
            .end()
            .find('.configure').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        });

        $('.column').sortable({
            connectWith: '.column',
            handle: 'h2',
            cursor: 'move',
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            opacity: 0.4,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                updateWidgetData();
            }
        })
        .disableSelection();
    });
```

My question is, how do I position the div's with the same id as the widgets name in document ready? For example, the div with the id CurrentDealsWidget is the first record in the table, with SortNo: 0, ColumnId: 1, Collapsed: 0, and UserId: 1. That means that this div needs to be in the div with the id "column1" and in the first position. I'm not very good with jQuery and javascript so I'm not sure how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: This is how I update the widget information..

jQuery

```
function updateWidgetData() {
        var items = [];
        $('.column').each(function () {
            var columnId = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.dragbox', this).each(function (i) {
                var collapsed = 0;
                if ($(this).find('.dragbox-content').css('display') == "none")
                    collapsed = 1;
                //Create Item object for current panel  
                var item = {
                    id: $(this).attr('id'),
                    collapsed: collapsed,
                    order: i,
                    column: columnId
                };
                //Push item object into items array  
                items.push(item);
            });
        });
        //Assign items array to sortorder JSON variable  
        var sortorder = { items: items };

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Handlers/SaveWidgets.ashx",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=uft-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(sortorder),
            success: function (response) {
                $("#console").html('<div class="success">Dashboard Saved</div>').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo(600, 1);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#console').delay(500).fadeTo(600, 0);
                }, 1000);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#console").html('<div class="fail">Dashboard was not saved!</div>').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeTo(600, 1);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#console').delay(500).fadeTo(600, 0);
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

AND my Handler..

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dboCao"].ConnectionString);

    string userId;

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string userName = context.User.Identity.Name;

        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmdUserId = new SqlCommand("SELECT UserId FROM tUser WHERE UserName = @UserName", conn))
        {
            cmdUserId.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);
            userId = Convert.ToString(cmdUserId.ExecuteScalar());

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(userId);
        }

        String json = String.Empty;
        // you have sent JSON to the server
        // read it into a string via the input stream
        using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            json = rd.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // create an instance of YourDataModel from the
        // json sent to this handler
        SaveWidgetsDAL data = null;
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(SaveWidgetsDAL));
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            ms.Write(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
            data = serializer.ReadObject(ms) as SaveWidgetsDAL;
        }
        // update the DB and
        // send back a JSON response
        int rowsUpdated = 0;

        foreach (var item in data.wdata)
        {
            string itemTitle = item.Title.Replace("FeaturedContent_", "");
            string itemColumn = item.ColumnId.Replace("FeaturedContent_column", "");

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tWidgets SET Title = @Title, SortNo = @SortNo, ColumnId = @ColumnId, Collapsed = @Collapsed "
                + "WHERE UserId = @UserId AND Title = @Title;", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnId", itemColumn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", itemTitle);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SortNo", item.SortNo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Collapsed", item.Collapsed);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        conn.Close();

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write("{ \"rows_updated\": " + rowsUpdated + " }");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 2:

With the solution below, I couldn't get it to work. Then I realized when I was updating the widget information, I had to remove FeaturedContent_column and FeaturedContent_ from the column and titles. So I figured I need to put them back in!

```
for (var i = 0; i < te.d.length; i++) {
    $('#FeaturedContent_column' + te.d[i].ColumnId).append($('#FeaturedContent_' + te.d[i].Title));
    if (te.d[i].Collapsed) {
                        //collapse
        $('#' + te.d[i].Title).children('.dragbox-content').css('display') == "none";
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
     for (var i = 0; i < te.d.length; i++) {
         $('#column'+te.d[i].ColumnId).append($('#'+te.d[i].Title));
         if (te.d[i].Collapsed)
         {
             //collapse
             $('#'+te.d[i].Title).children(".dragbox-content').css('display') = "none";
         }
     }
```

This selects the correct column and appends the widget to it based upon the sorting of the array.

`$('#column'+te.d[i].ColumnId)`: The generic `$` function of jQuery allows us to select elements in the DOM through a wide range of selectors. Since your widgets have ids we use the id selector `#`. In this case we append the index to the string column to build the correct column selector.

Once the correct column is selected we're appending the widget to it by using `.append` and providing the element selected by `$('#'+te.d[i].Title)`. This removes the element from its previous location and adds it to this column (`div`).

Comment: Thanks for a reply! I just gave this a shot. I don't receive any errors but the widget's aren't being loaded to their new locations after they are saved to the database and after a page refresh. I have verified their new locations are being saved but after page refresh, they are back to their defaults. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have updated my question and provided how I am updating the widget information.

Comment: Could this be a problem? I feel it could be since it was when I was saving the widgets. When I was saving the widgets I had to replace FeaturedContent_ and FeaturedContent_column. To position it, would I have to add those back since I'm using content placeholders?

Comment: Seems to me your update code passes `order = index` to server, but you expect `item.SortNo` and you expect item.Title while `id` is passed. I think nothing gets updated since it cannot find an db row with title null.

Comment: It is getting updated. The problem was the featured content. I'll accept your answer because without it, I wouldn't be able to figure it out!! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Glad to be of service.